# Do I need to explicitly declare all component properties (vue.js)?

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a component which is a kind of glorified input control, which will save a lot of the repetitive HTML of forms with Bootstrap grids (having to put a label next to each one, assign a 'for' attribute to it, assign a 'form-control' class to the input, etc.). The idea is that the component contains an input control with default values (such as the 'form-control' class) already set, label prepended, etc.

The HTML 'input' control as a whole bunch of optional attributes, some of which I may wish to use at some point - readonly, disabled, placeholder, etc. Do I actually have to declare all of these upfront, as it were, in my component's properties, if I may use one or more of them? This is a bit of a nuisance and rather cumbersome if true. It would be handy if all attributes which weren't explicitly declared were simply made available in the component's scope.

This is, I imagine, a common enough requirement that maybe there's another way of doing this?

Comment: I guess, if you have a `prop` named `inputAttrs` with different attribute and values, you can do `<input v-bind="inputAttrs" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare all of them, you can use `v-bind` to bind an object of optional attributes. So, in your parent you can do:

```
<custom-input :optional-attrs="{placeholder: 'Type something!'}"></custom-input>
```

Then in your component simply add it as a prop:

```
 props: {
   optionalAttrs: {}
 }
```

And use `v-bind` on your input in your component:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-bind="optionalAttrs">
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rww551og/

Comment: I had just started exploring that approach myself, so it's great to see that it's viable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare all props which CAN BE USED, but you have to add REQUIRE: TRUE only on those which are required. That's all.

Comment: OK, so I was right in that it's cumbersome to do what I wish. The HTML input tag has over 30 possible attributes. To have to declare all of these in my component properties feels like a bad design, even if it wouldn't actually take that long to do.